# Seemingly unable to access content generated in the link() function while attempting to unit test an angular directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, directive

I am working on an enterprise project, and as a part of that project we have a directive for creating form fields with appropriate document markup and validation/error handling. As an example, consider something like the following:

```
<form name="myForm">
<my-form-field label="My Field">
<input type="text" name="myField" id="myField" ng-model="myField" ng-required="true" />
</my-form-field>
</form>
```

The directive works exactly as expected, properly surrounding my input field with the common/expected markup, adding appropriate event handlers, etc.

One key piece of functionality is a convenience feature where the directive "notices" that the child form field has an attribute value for ng-required of true (either directly, as in this example, or because it is bound to something which is evaluated). This attribute does the "normal" angular thing (hooking into field-level validation in the angular workflow), but then my directive also notices it's presence in the child element, and appends " *" to the label value when taking the label attribute of the directive element and creating an HTML  as part of the markup which is generated.

When attempting to unit test this in jasmine/karma, I see the logic in the template() portion of my directive firing (e.g., the  tag is generated), but not the items in the link() portion (e.g., adding the asterisk to the label text, updating the for="" attribute of the label tag to match the id="" attribute of the child  tag).

After spending the morning researching various demos/tutorials on unit testing angular directives, I found an example which didn't help me much...but did offer a smaller/more basic example of what I am seeing: http://plnkr.co/edit/tirhLwFEXLKSzukbsW1q?p=preview

In this example, seeing the attribute values set by the link() function of the direction is easily handled (see the expectations at lines 23-25), but the rendered html still doesn't seem to be compiled (outputting element.html() anywhere in that it() still shows the angular variables - like {{values.center}} - instead of the compiled values). I recognize that I could put computed values on the scope and then follow this pattern of validating by checking the directive's scope...but in my case, I am further modifying the html within the link() portion (quite successfully actually, despite what the unit tests appear to be showing).

What am I missing in terms of being able to "see"/validate the compiled HTML (e.g., validate that an asterisk was added to the label text when appropriate)? I thought about doing all of my markup work in the template() portion of my directive, but then I can't see how I could inspect the child input element (to get the id for the for="" attribute of the label, and to check if it is required or not so that I know if the asterisk is appropriate for the label text).

**EDIT:**
 - This plunkr is most advanced of my three scenarios, and fails (basically a copy of my code, including trying to combine all the angular template generation/compilation into one common function, based on an example I had seen in a few different places): http://plnkr.co/edit/AxGAUKYFvm2yf1vPsWD3?p=preview

In the third plunkr (see my comment below for the first two, each of which works as expected), the error thrown is actually "TypeError: currentSpec.queue is undefined...", which is likely my culprit - but I can't seem to find a way around it. I actually wasn't seeing this error locally...because I had seen some advice in a few places to change this method within angular-mocks.js:

```
isSpecRunning = function() {
    //return currentSpec && (window.mocha || currentSpec.queue.running);
      return !!currentSpec;
  };
```

The second line is the original, which was commented out/replaced with the third line. This removes the error shown in the Plunk, and instead my unit test runs just fine...except for it doesn't seem to show the final compiled version (e.g. the label's *for* attribute is never populated, and the asterisk is not added to the label text when appropriate). So with the suggested change, my test runs ok - but fails to see the 
"final" markup which I see when I actually run my site. Without the change to angular-mock.js, I see the error you see in the plunkr.

Comment: Can you create a Plunker that replicates an isolated version of the problem, perhaps only the appending of the asterisk?

Comment: I added a link to a Plunker which fails up above in the main description. Two other Plunkers which may be of use:

 - This plunkr is as basic as I could make it, and this seems to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/dRiunJiylg8VE0xB4L0e?p=preview
 - This plunkr is "un-optimized", and also seems to work (basically a copy of my code with some names/variables changed, minus the optimization of trying to combine all the angular template generation/compilation into one common function): http://plnkr.co/edit/7xWn7IVQmZM4u3zh9q1V?p=preview

Comment: Essentially, the difference between what works and what fails seems to be my attempted use of a common function to handle my angular template generation/compilation (see the compileDirective() function in my Plunker linked in the edit to the original question).